# What is a DBI and what is it used for?

Tags: perl, dbi

I'm wondering what is DBI, what is it used for and is there such thing as "DBI database"

Comment: Did you read the tag wiki?

Comment: The [tag:dbi] tag is for questions about the Perl DBI (DataBase Interface) module and its DBD (DataBase Driver) sub-modules.  In the context of Perl, the DBI module provides a more-or-less uniform means of accessing a variety of DBMS — those DBMS for which a database driver exists.  In principle, you can switch between DBMS by changing the connection request only; in practice, it usually isn't quite that simple, but it's a good approximation.

Answer (score 6):

How did this question make it ten years without an answer?! :)

Perl's [DBI](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI) is "DataBase Interface", a thing invented by Tim Bunce. It's a general interface for connecting to many different database servers without having to know server-specific interfaces. Each supported server has a "DBD" (DataBase Driver). For example, [DBD::Pg](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::Pg) is the DBI backend for Postgres. And, the nice thing is that the DBI project doesn't have to make the DBDs. Anyone can write a DBD to support whatever they want, and different groups can support the individual drivers so development can progress at different rates. I think anyone who has used databases and perl together probably owes Tim at least one night at the pub.

You could, for example, use DBI to connect to MySQL, then change the backend to Postgres without changing the code. Mostly. You can still do server-specific things, but those are edge cases. You might have to update or change some queries, but the way you send queries, receive results, and iterate through results would be the same.

With this unified interface, it's possible to do weird things like start with a "database" backed by CSV files, later change to SQLite without changing code, then change to Postgres without changing code (all assuming simple schema with simple queries). That doesn't seem magical today, but when Tim Bunce first invented DBI, it was like wizard magic.

Back in the day, you could compile different versions of perl based on the database you wanted to use. Things like "oraperl" and "syperl" existed—you'd compile perl against those specific vendor libraries and you'd have to use the interface that the oracle or sybase libraries provided. You were then locked into that. New library version? Time to recompile perl.